# Trouble passing locals in Partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials, locals

I have a partial called _avatar.html.erb
I want to pass in an id as a local variable called entity_id which will be the id of an object.

```
<% form_tag({:controller => "avatar", :action => "upload", :id => entity_id},
     :multipart => true ) do %>
    <fieldset>
      <legend><%= title %></legend>
      <% if avatar.exists? %>
      <%= avatar_tag(avatar) %>
      [<%= link_to "delete", {:controller => "avatar",:action => "delete", 
           :id => entity_id},:confirm => "Are you sure" %>]
     ...
```

Here is the call for the parital:

```
<%= render :partial => 'avatar/avatar', :locals => {:avatar => @avatar, 
    :title => @title, :entity_id => @board.id } %>
```

When I try this I get the following errors:

```
undefined local variable or method `entity_id' for #<ActionView::Base:0x2736bb0>
```

When I take that out I also get an error telling me it can't find the local variable "title".

Can anyone help this seems to be the correct way to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you 100% certain the error traces are coming from avatar/_avatar.html.erb? Maybe the undefined variables are being referenced in the main template.

Comment: yeah..I also dont see any problem with your code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using :id=>@entity_id (note the @ symbol preceding the name). Likewise, @title, instead of "title".

Comment: Hey thanks, I found that after I restarted my computer cleared out the cache for some reason everything worked. I did not want to use the instance variables because from what I read its bad practice and makes the code more difficult to maintain. For some reason I have a ghost in the machine. Thanks for all the help though :)